How to reduce the size of R plotly html output by rounding plot values
I am trying to reduce the size of my RMarkdown html report and more importantly, make them faster to open. The html report consists of a large number of R Plotly plots with each plot containing a large number of data points (1000+). Considering that R Plotly stores all of the raw data for each plot within the html file, I believed a good option to reduce the file size was to round the decimal places in the data. However, I found that even though the input data was rounded, R Plotly still maintains a large number of decimals places in the html file. Consequently the file size is not reduced if data is rounded.
See below for 2 cases, the base containing raw data, and the rounding case containing rounded data. The file size is the same for both cases.
Base Case HTML
RawData <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2024/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12),
                      PreciseValue = c(0.1516270, 0.3542629, 0.8339342, 0.5796813, 0.3933472, 0.2937137, 0.1779205, 0.4285533, 0.6841885, 0.3399411,0.99476560, 0.42941527))
RawData$RoundValue <- round(RawData$PreciseValue,2)
fig <- plot_ly(RawData, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')%>%
  add_trace(x = ~Date, y = ~PreciseValue, name = 'PreciseValue')
saveWidget(fig, "plotly_base.html", selfcontained = TRUE)

The html file size is 3780kb.
If I open the html file and look at the underlying R Plotly data, the stored y data is:
"y":[0.15162704353000001,0.35426295622999998,0.83393426323999997,0.57968136341999998,0.39334726234,0.29371352347000002,0.17792423404999999,0.44352285533000002,0.68418423485000002,0.36623994110000002,0.99476432455999997,0.42941523452699998]

Notice that there are more decimals places than in the original data.
Rounding Values Case
RawData$RoundValue <- round(RawData$PreciseValue,2)
fig <- plot_ly(RawData, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')%>%
  add_trace(x = ~Date, y = ~RoundValue, name = 'RoundValue')

saveWidget(fig, "plotly_round.html", selfcontained = TRUE)

The html file size for the round case is also 3780kb.
The underlying data for this case is
"y":[0.14999999999999999,0.34999999999999998,0.82999999999999996,0.57999999999999996,0.39000000000000001,0.28999999999999998,0.17999999999999999,0.44,0.68000000000000005,0.37,0.98999999999999999,0.42999999999999999]

The stored y data should be something like
"y":[0.15, 0.35, 0.83, 0.58, 0.39, 0.29, 0.18, 0.44, 0.68, 0.37, 0.99, 0.43]

Does anyone know how to configure R Plotly to only store the configured number of decimal places in html output?

plotly uses htmlwidgets methods to save its data.  Part of that is that the object being plotted contains a function to save its data as JSON.  The function used in your example is
> attr(fig$x, "TOJSON_FUNC")
function (x, ...) 
{
    jsonlite::toJSON(x, digits = 50, auto_unbox = TRUE, force = TRUE, 
        null = "null", na = "null", time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6", 
        ...)
}
<bytecode: 0x12084ae50>
<environment: namespace:plotly>

You can replace that with a different function, e.g. one that looks just the same, but only tries to save 2 significant digits instead of 50 significant digits:
attr(fig$x, "TOJSON_FUNC") <- function (x, ...) 
{
  jsonlite::toJSON(x, digits = 2, auto_unbox = TRUE, force = TRUE, 
                   null = "null", na = "null", time_format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS6", 
                   ...)
}

saveWidget(fig, "plotly_base.html", selfcontained = TRUE)

When I do that, it saves the data with just 2 decimal places.
This doesn't make a huge difference to the file size since most of it is the plotly Javascript code, but on a larger dataset (maybe your real one) it should help a bit.

This looks like a great option to reduce the number of stored decimals places. How do I make the change? I assume I have to edit the call from Plotly to the toJSON function. Do I have to modify Plotly's source code?

@Anthony : No, the code I posted is all you need to do.  Calculate the figure in the normal way, then modify its TOJSON_FUNC attribute, then save it in the normal way.

I don't think digits=2 is the right thing to do here (or in the other answers), because it truncates small values, e.g., a plot with x values in the range .001-.009 would have only values 0 and .01. It would be better to figure out how many digits are required for the plot to still be meaningful, e.g., by calculating using for digits= the result of something like min(0, -log10(diff(range(x))) + 2L). It makes one wonder why the plotly author doesn't do this, perhaps because the loss of precision is (often) important, e.g., when displaying at high resolution.

@MartinMorgan : If you use digits = I(2) it will use signif() instead of round(), so you'll always get two significant digits.  And if you have a more complicated example where some columns need different handling than others, that's also possible with this approach, though it's more work.  In the TOJSON_FUNC function you'd first do the rounding on each column, then call jsonlite::toJSON() with digits = NA.

This worked really well for my problem. I could also change the format of the date time to remove some unnecessary 000's. I used the solution on my larger problem and it reduced the html file size from 47MB to 42Mb. Thanks user2554330.

You can do this
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)

RawData <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(as.Date("2024/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12),
  PreciseValue = c(0.1516270, 0.3542629, 0.8339342, 0.5796813, 0.3933472, 0.2937137, 0.1779205, 0.4285533, 0.6841885, 0.3399411, 0.99476560, 0.42941527)
)

fig <- plot_ly(RawData, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Date, y = ~PreciseValue, name = 'PreciseValue')

saveWidget(fig, "plotly_base.html", selfcontained = TRUE)

html_content <- readLines("plotly_base.html")
html_content <- gsub(
  pattern = "([0-9]+\\.[0-9]{2})[0-9]*", 
  replacement = "\\1", 
  x = html_content
)

writeLines(html_content, "plotly_rounded.html")

which gives

and in the html you'll have
<script type="application/json" data-for="htmlwidget-f7b8f28dbb6776fbb0e5">{"x":{"visdat":{"60443a954e78":["function () ","plotlyVisDat"]},"cur_data":"60443a954e78","attrs":{"60443a954e78":{"mode":"lines","alpha_stroke":1,"sizes":[10,100],"spans":[1,20],"type":"scatter"},"60443a954e78.1":{"mode":"lines","alpha_stroke":1,"sizes":[10,100],"spans":[1,20],"type":"scatter","x":{},"y":["0.15","0.35","0.83","0.58","0.39","0.29","0.18","0.43","0.68","0.34","0.99","0.43"],"name":"RoundValue","inherit":true}},"layout":{"margin":{"b":40,"l":60,"t":25,"r":10},"xaxis":{"domain":[0,1],"automargin":true,"title":"Date"},"yaxis":{"domain":[0,1],"automargin":true,"title":[]},"hovermode":"closest","showlegend":true},"source":"A","config":{"modeBarButtonsToAdd":["hoverclosest","hovercompare"],"showSendToCloud":false},"data":[{"mode":"lines","type":"scatter","marker":{"color":"rgba(31,119,180,1)","line":{"color":"rgba(31,119,180,1)"}},"error_y":{"color":"rgba(31,119,180,1)"},"error_x":{"color":"rgba(31,119,180,1)"},"line":{"color":"rgba(31,119,180,1)"},"xaxis":"x","yaxis":"y","frame":null},{"mode":"lines","type":"scatter","x":["2024-01-01","2024-02-01","2024-03-01","2024-04-01","2024-05-01","2024-06-01","2024-07-01","2024-08-01","2024-09-01","2024-10-01","2024-11-01","2024-12-01"],"y":["0.15","0.35","0.83","0.58","0.39","0.29","0.18","0.43","0.68","0.34","0.99","0.43"],"name":"RoundValue","marker":{"color":"rgba(255,127,14,1)","line":{"color":"rgba(255,127,14,1)"}},"error_y":{"color":"rgba(255,127,14,1)"},"error_x":{"color":"rgba(255,127,14,1)"},"line":{"color":"rgba(255,127,14,1)"},"xaxis":"x","yaxis":"y","frame":null}],"highlight":{"on":"plotly_click","persistent":false,"dynamic":false,"selectize":false,"opacityDim":0.20000000000000001,"selected":{"opacity":1},"debounce":0},"shinyEvents":["plotly_hover","plotly_click","plotly_selected","plotly_relayout","plotly_brushed","plotly_brushing","plotly_clickannotation","plotly_doubleclick","plotly_deselect","plotly_afterplot","plotly_sunburstclick"],"base_url":"https://plot.ly"},"evals":[],"jsHooks":[]}</script>



The roundvalue calculation results in an error (Unexpected [).

My bad. I accidentally pasted the image link in the code. Edited it.

I don't see how this is different from my Rounding Values case. It looks exactly the same? The html file will still contain the extra decimal places.

I modified my code and added the html output part which contains the rounded values. Check if this is what you were expecting.

The fig plot doesn't work and gives a warning message:Can't display both discrete & non-discrete data on same axis. It is doing this because the RoundValue column has a character format due to the sprintf function.

I changed the approach to this. It should work for you as well.

When you make a plot using a data.frame, plotly saves the underlying data.frame in the browser, so it doesn't matter which columns you use to plot if you don't remove them from the underlying data.frame.
In the example below:

For new plot - notice how if you remove the PreciseValue column, it is not passed to your figure.
Also consider if you are passing a lot of other columns in your real dataset, you might want to remove them.

library(dplyr)
library(plotly)


# your fig ----------------------------------------------------------------
RawData <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2024/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12),
                      PreciseValue = c(0.1516270, 0.3542629, 0.8339342, 0.5796813, 0.3933472, 0.2937137, 0.1779205, 0.4285533, 0.6841885, 0.3399411,0.99476560, 0.42941527))
RawData$RoundValue <- round(RawData$PreciseValue,2)
fig <- plot_ly(RawData, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')%>%
  add_trace(x = ~Date, y = ~PreciseValue, name = 'PreciseValue')

plotly::plotly_data(fig)
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#>    Date       PreciseValue RoundValue
#>    <date>            <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 2024-01-01        0.152       0.15
#>  2 2024-02-01        0.354       0.35
#>  3 2024-03-01        0.834       0.83
#>  4 2024-04-01        0.580       0.58
#>  5 2024-05-01        0.393       0.39
#>  6 2024-06-01        0.294       0.29
#>  7 2024-07-01        0.178       0.18
#>  8 2024-08-01        0.429       0.43
#>  9 2024-09-01        0.684       0.68
#> 10 2024-10-01        0.340       0.34
#> 11 2024-11-01        0.995       0.99
#> 12 2024-12-01        0.429       0.43


# new fig -----------------------------------------------------------------
RawData <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(as.Date("2024/1/1"), by = "month", length.out = 12),
  PreciseValue = c(0.1516270, 0.3542629, 0.8339342, 0.5796813, 0.3933472, 0.2937137, 0.1779205, 0.4285533, 0.6841885, 0.3399411,0.99476560, 0.42941527)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
    RoundValue = round(PreciseValue, 2)
  ) %>% 
  select(
    Date, RoundValue
  )


fig2 <- plot_ly(RawData, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines')%>%
  add_trace(x = ~Date, y = ~RoundValue, name = 'RoundValue')


plotly::plotly_data(fig2)
#> # A tibble: 12 × 2
#>    Date       RoundValue
#>    <date>          <dbl>
#>  1 2024-01-01       0.15
#>  2 2024-02-01       0.35
#>  3 2024-03-01       0.83
#>  4 2024-04-01       0.58
#>  5 2024-05-01       0.39
#>  6 2024-06-01       0.29
#>  7 2024-07-01       0.18
#>  8 2024-08-01       0.43
#>  9 2024-09-01       0.68
#> 10 2024-10-01       0.34
#> 11 2024-11-01       0.99
#> 12 2024-12-01       0.43

Created on 2024-05-20 with reprex v2.1.0

I tried this approach but when I saved fig2 using saveWidget, the html file size was the same and the number of decimals places in the files were still excessively large.

Another option with xml2 to modify directly the generated .html.
Original data : Chapter 2 Interactive graphs Data Visualization with R
Input (data of the first graph) :
[1] "{\"x\":{\"data\":[{\"x\":[0.0328321225432224,0.109320252277505,0.293389955686854,0.25579692457896,0.039311241065627,0.146064301552106,0.181909295915811,0.311815561959654,0.317128096436614,0.0955315870570108,0.136271785804496,0.0546152503926016,0.0613091709712931,0.0890071477017791,0.234544596507787,0.171584073331424,0.0137459607258265,0.0647079899677535,0.494673295454545,0.472161572052402,0.0830819851933096,0.1285972177976,0.123681687440077,0.0317001620035903,0.0190664607303797,0.191960252935863,0.212282255683496,0.546967895362664,0.211626387981711,0.0487558624283481,0.124644280022766,0.547699386503067,0.0800054704595186,0.0850793972908528,0.209757716561567,0.037748128864302,0.109842719431761,0.0941492343551766,0.0636989670437777,0.174081035923141,0.0699268354217475,0.0638297872340425,0.132262282832057,0.0656909202078875,0.0357040323633042,0.0145872865275142,0.00785264738148854,0.511931766627348,0.340971780182474,0.00423536530025715,0.184762773722628,0.00249500998003992,0.104696511947267,0.0480663303762973,0.0370172390752372,0.0981524249422633,0.0967281719611946,0.0999784063917081,0.0915903413821815,0.152237710931768,0.0062984496124031,0.21302783563719,0.244618964514252,0.171130648129217,0.0188772975658222,0.272753623188406,0.152310409104287,0.0394015701377574,0.10632216760032,0.0971946727118164,0.183070866141732,0.000505433409148345,0.143502257902659,0.139184397163121,0.0550271444082519,0.0418168914123492,0.193761696818465,0.030040733197556,0.00514917461759806,0.252943155062227,0.0354451008352007,0.136290021178522],

Code to round each plotly data element to 2 digits :
###Packages
library(rvest)
library(xml2)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)

### Parse the generated HTML file
src=read_html("c://Users/your_name/Downloads/markdown_with_plotly.htm")
### Locate the script elements which contain the data
ext=src %>% html_elements(xpath = "//script[@data-for]")

### Write a function to round the data of plotly graphs
### First, extract the json data and pull out the dataframe containing the numbers
### Then, apply a function to specific columns (here x & y) to round data
### Overwrite the original dataframe with the new one
### Convert back the parsed JSON (list) to JSON (character)
### Extract the attributes of the script element
### Create a new sibling node (script) with the JSON object previously created
### Set the attributes of the new script node with the attributes previously extracted
### To finish remove the original script node

babar=function(x){json=fromJSON(html_text2(x))
df=json[["x"]][["data"]]
fix=df %>% mutate(across(c(x,y),~map(.x,function(x){round(x,digits = 2)})))
json$x$data<-fix
new=toJSON(json)
attrs=x %>% 
  html_attrs() %>% 
  unlist()
xml_set_attrs(xml_add_sibling(x, .value = "script", new),value = attrs)
xml_remove(x)
}

### We apply the funtion to each script elements
walk(ext,babar,.progress = TRUE)

### Write a new HTML file
write_html(src,"C://Users/your_name/Downloads/plotly.html")

Output (data for the first graph) :
[1] "{\"x\":{\"data\":[{\"x\":[0.03,0.11,0.29,0.26,0.04,0.15,0.18,0.31,0.32,0.1,0.14,0.05,0.06,0.09,0.23,0.17,0.01,0.06,0.49,0.47,0.08,0.13,0.12,0.03,0.02,0.19,0.21,0.55,0.21,0.05,0.12,0.55,0.08,0.09,0.21,0.04,0.11,0.09,0.06,0.17,0.07,0.06,0.13,0.07,0.04,0.01,0.01,0.51,0.34,0,0.18,0,0.1,0.05,0.04,0.1,0.1,0.1,0.09,0.15,0.01,0.21,0.24,0.17,0.02,0.27,0.15,0.04,0.11,0.1,0.18,0,0.14,0.14,0.06,0.04,0.19,0.03,0.01,0.25,0.04,0.14],


This approach is a bit more complicated than user2554330's approach.
